# Postfix operator along with sizeof operator

Tags: c, sizeof, postfix-operator, prefix-operator

```
int x = 97; int y = sizeof(x++);

printf("Value of x = %d", x);
```

Output: 97 I am expecting 98 but answer is 97.

Anybody can explain?

Comment: Seems like sizeof looks only at type of expression.